# How to inherit from a base class, when the inheriting class requires the inherited class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

Given the following requirements:

1. We have the classes `Foundation` and `Data`
2. `Data` is a child class of `Foundation`
3. Instances of `Foundation` hold an instance of `Data`

`Python` code:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class Foundation():
    data: Data

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = Data()

class Data(Foundation):
    pass

Foundation()
```

However, the given script exits with an `RecursionError`. Why and how can I implement the three given requirements?

Comment: Apart from that it is not possible what you would like to do, you do realize that you have both a static member `data` and an instance member `data` there, right?

Comment: Why `Data` need to inheriting Foundation? This causes a cyclical dependence

Comment: @DamiãoMartins `Foundation` implements basic features for all my classes. However, `Foundation` may contain `Data`.

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3 This way every time you instantiate a Data, the constructor of the Foundation was called and it call Data constructor and so on. Because that the `RecursionError` happens

Answer (score 1):

You can use `super` to avoid calling an object that calls an object that calls an object... and so on untill recursion error.

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Foundation():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        print(self.data)

class Data(Foundation):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Data, self).__init__(self)

Data()
```

Now you called `Data`, and data's `super` is a `Foundation`, which holds a reference to it's child.

[Tutorial](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function)

Comment: What if we have to use `__new__()`, becauase `Foundation` is implemented with it?

Comment: Python's init is the generat initial function. If you would like to use __new__(), or any other funtion, you can access it through super. Implement it the right way. Check python classes for further information!

Comment: You can just call `super()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/21974

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I solved the problem by checking if the current class (from `__new__()`) is `Data`. If so, `self.data` is not being assigned: `if cls is not Data: instance.data = Data()`